# ajaxForm unable to POST file

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, jquery, ajaxform

### What I'm trying to do

I have a form which is posted via [`ajaxForm`](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/). The form contains a `file` input field, however the data isn't being processed with the rest of the information in the `POST`.

### The code

**HTML Form**

```
<form id="profilepicForm" action="user/profilepic.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" accept="image/gif, image/jpeg, image/png" name="file" />
    <input type="hidden" name="userid" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['user']['id'] ?>" />
    <input type="submit" value="Upload">
</form>
```

**Javascript**

```
var options = { 
    complete: function(response) {
        $("#profilepicMessage").html(response.responseText);
    },
    error: function(){
        $("#profilepicMessage").html("ERROR: unable to upload file");
    } 
};

$("#profilepicForm").ajaxForm(options);
```

**PHP**

```
$user_id    = $_POST['userid'];
$image      = $_FILES['file']['name'];

print_r($_POST);
exit;
```

### What's happening

All that comes through is `Array ( [userid] => 34 )`, where 34 is my particular `userid`. Therefore I know that the form *is* being posted, but the file is not going through.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously-with-jquery?rq=1 You need to use HTML5 to do ajax file uploads. You are using the ajaxForm jQuery plugin which probably does not support file uploads.

Comment: [This website tutorial says otherwise](http://hayageek.com/ajax-file-upload-jquery/), and is apparently fully functional.

Comment: If you want to make a nice uploader, plupload is a good solution. Worth to give a look.

Comment: [look here](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#code-samples) the plugin page gives examples of file uploads

Answer (score 1):

You should look at global variable [$_FILES](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php).

Comment: Yes thanks for this. It can see the file and successfully shows the array but it won't upload the file.

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php -> may some examples could help you in that case.

Answer (score -1):

You'll have to look for something like uploadifive to manage that, for ajax can't currently handle file transfers

(this is not entirely true, there is [ajax2 and html5 file api](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/xhr2/), but save yourself a problem, look for uploadifive).